# How to create dynamically JButton value in DesignGridLayout library?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grid-layout

i create grid layout using DesignGridLayout java library [(here)](http://designgridlayout.java.net/usage.html).
in the sampe if create 3 column layout. 
 using this code :

```
layout.row().add(new JButton("Button 1")).add(new JButton("Button 2")).add(new JButton("Button 3"));
```

or using method that return object :

```
layout.row().add(button()).add(button()).add(button());
...
...
public JButton button() {
    return new JButton("Button");
}
```

*The question is, how to create dynamically JButton value? May be name,icon or anything?*
I already try my own code like this :

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
    layout.row().add(button).add(button).add(button);   
}
```

it return : 
**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Do not add the same component twice**

My purpose for different value in each component which added in panel is, i want to create gallery that populate
different image, and i load that images using looping, like this :

```
for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    ...
    ImageIcon imgSource = new ImageIcon(new File(myPath));
    JLabel labelGallery = new JLabel(imgSource);
    ...
}
```

Any solution?
Thanks before :)

Answer (score 2):

In your example,

```
layout.row().add(button).add(button).add(button);
```

has the effect of attempting to add the *same* `JButton` instance to the row repeatedly.

In the [example cited](http://designgridlayout.java.net/usage.html),

```
layout.row().grid().add(button()).add(button());
```

invokes an auxiliary method, `button()`, to create a new instance each time it appears:

```
public static JButton button() {
    return new JButton("Button");
}
```

Comment: So, how i can implement my method, which have different icon in each JButton?

Comment: One approach would be to pass the desired icon as a parameter to the factory method, `button()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @trashgod, Swing does not allow to add the same component twice to a panel.
If you want to add several components, created within a loop, to the same row, you can do it as follows:

```
IRow row = layout.row().grid();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    JButton button = createButton(i);
    row.add(button);
}
```

That will create only one row with `n` buttons inside.